# how to add translation feature in custom module (hook_node_view) using google translation api key?

Tags: hooks

I want to write a code to translate any node (content type: blog) into any other language using a button to translate. I purchased google translate api key but I do not understand how to implement it using hook_node_view with a button.

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this module helps you [GTranslate](https://www.drupal.org/project/gtranslate)

Comment: Thank you. But, actually I already have google translate api keys and if I install GTranslate module then again I have to pay for GTranslate api. That's why I requisite for some solution other than this.